# Debugging: OwnCloud horribly slow

Tags: debugging, cloud

I am trying to figure out why my OwnCloud installation stalls of 10s of seconds before it runs again for 10s of seconds normally.

What kind of debugging can I enable on OwnCloud (server+client), so I can see why it stalls?

There is plenty of free RAM:

```
$ free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      16403620    7782404    8621216          0     116104    6752432
-/+ buffers/cache:     913868   15489752
Swap:      8146940          0    8146940
```

The disk is 0% busy when owncloud is stalled (marked (stalled) below) and 5% busy when owncloud resumes (marked (OK) below):

```
$ iostat -dkx 3|grep sda
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda (OK)          2.27     3.77   28.82   34.49  2521.20   450.23    93.88     1.08   17.04    8.96   23.80   5.15  32.63
sda               0.00     0.00   15.33    1.33  1888.00    45.33   232.00     0.05    3.12    1.74   19.00   1.60   2.67
sda (stalled)     0.00     0.00    0.00   12.67     0.00    49.33     7.79     0.03    2.63    0.00    2.63   1.26   1.60
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    5.33     0.00    20.00     7.50     0.01    2.75    0.00    2.75   2.75   1.47
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    6.33     0.00    24.00     7.58     0.02    3.37    0.00    3.37   2.32   1.47
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.33     0.00     1.33     8.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda               0.00     1.00    0.00    9.33     0.00    40.00     8.57     0.09    9.57    0.00    9.57   5.57   5.20
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda               0.00     3.33    6.33   28.00   720.00   124.00    49.17     1.62   47.11    2.74   57.14   2.37   8.13
sda               0.00     0.00   42.00    0.00  5342.67     0.00   254.41     0.02    0.48    0.48    0.00   0.48   2.00
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    8.64     0.00    34.55     8.00     0.01    1.54    0.00    1.54   1.54   1.33
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    5.67     0.00    21.33     7.53     0.02    3.76    0.00    3.76   3.76   2.13
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    6.67     0.00    25.33     7.60     0.01    2.00    0.00    2.00   2.00   1.33
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda               0.00     0.00    0.33    8.67     5.33    33.33     8.59     0.02    2.22   12.00    1.85   2.22   2.00
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    8.33     0.00    32.00     7.68     0.02    2.40    0.00    2.40   2.40   2.00
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda               0.00     4.33    0.00   26.00     0.00   160.00    12.31     1.05   40.46    0.00   40.46   3.08   8.00
sda               0.00     1.67    0.00   12.33     0.00    57.33     9.30     0.06    5.19    0.00    5.19   3.03   3.73
sda (OK)          0.00     0.00   61.67    0.00  7802.67     0.00   253.06     0.10    1.62    1.62    0.00   1.43   8.80
sda               0.00     0.00   49.00    4.33  6229.33    16.00   234.20     0.08    1.55    1.44    2.77   1.12   6.00
sda               0.00     0.00   62.67    0.00  8021.33     0.00   256.00     0.03    0.57    0.57    0.00   0.55   3.47
sda               0.00     0.00   60.00    7.67  7680.00    29.33   227.86     0.07    1.04    1.00    1.39   0.81   5.47
sda               0.00     0.00   53.33    0.67  6729.33     2.67   249.33     0.06    1.09    1.10    0.00   0.99   5.33
sda               0.00     8.00   56.67    1.00  7253.33    34.67   252.76     0.05    0.95    0.68   16.00   0.90   5.20
sda               0.00     0.00   56.00    0.00  7168.00     0.00   256.00     0.03    0.55    0.55    0.00   0.55   3.07
sda               0.00     0.00   59.00    3.00  7509.33    10.67   242.58     0.05    0.88    0.81    2.22   0.80   4.93
sda               0.00     0.00   56.00    0.00  7088.00     0.00   253.14     0.04    0.71    0.71    0.00   0.62   3.47
sda               0.00     2.67   16.00   34.00  1957.33   145.33    84.11     0.11    2.11    1.08    2.59   0.80   4.00
sda               0.00     0.00    9.67    5.33  1237.33    20.00   167.64     0.03    2.04    2.21    1.75   1.51   2.27
sda (stalled)     0.00     0.00    0.00    1.33     0.00     8.00    12.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00   10.33     0.00    40.00     7.74     0.03    2.58    0.00    2.58   1.29   1.33
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.67     0.00     2.67     8.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    8.33     0.00    32.00     7.68     0.03    3.68    0.00    3.68   3.20   2.67
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda               0.00     0.00    4.67    4.00   597.33    14.67   141.23     0.02    2.62    2.86    2.33   2.00   1.73
```

There is plenty of data to sync, plenty of bandwidth and no packet loss.

ownCloud version 6.0.0a (stable)

Comment: The actual stable version of owncloud is 8.2.1, perhaps the first thing to do is to update your install. Could you give more information ?

Comment: What other information would you like?

Comment: Did you try to disable all the third apps ? is your php config correct ? did this happens each time you run your server or is there a period after the installation where the server ran without trouble ? did you use encryption on the server side ? ...

Comment: No third party apps enabled. How do I check if php is correctly configured? The problem is intermittent: It can run for several minutes with no problem and then suddenly stall. https server side encryption - no file encryption.

Answer (score 0):

In desperation I tried sending all packets twice:

```
for IF in `ifconfig -a|grep '^[a-z]'|field 1`; do
  sudo tc qdisc del dev $IF root
  sudo tc qdisc add dev $IF root netem duplicate 100% reorder 100% gap 1 delay 300ms
done
```

That helped: While not getting the full bandwidth I now get a consistent flow at around 60% of the bandwidth.

The client is behind NAT and just maybe the NAT-wall makes an error in NATting now and then.